# How to access this checkbox using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to know if a input type="checkbox" that comes just before a label is checked or not using javascript. The only thing I know is that the label has "Service Provider" in it

```
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UserTypeList_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UserTypeList$2" />
<label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UserTypeList_2">Service Provider</label>
```

Tried this and failed.

```
$('label[text="Service Provider"]').prev().is(':checked')
```

What could I do?

Disclaimer: Its the markup rendered by ASP.NET 2.0 WebForms for a CheckBoxList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To search the text of an element, you need to use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

```
$('label:contains("Service Provider")').prev().is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("label:contains('Service Provider')").prev().is(':checked')` should work